# How can I use NTLM or Kerberos authentication with Mojo::UserAgent

Tags: perl, ntlm, mojolicious

I am trying to get Mojo::UserAgent to authenticate via NTLM. Rougly like this:

```
use Mojo::UserAgent;
use Mojo::URL;
use Data::Dump qw/dump/;
use Path::Tiny;
use Authen::NTLM;

$\ = "\n"; $|++;

my $ntlm = Authen::NTLM-> new(host => "some.hidden.pl", user => 'foo',
              domain   => "bar", password => "baz", version  => 2);

my $xml = path($ARGV[0])->slurp;

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
my $url = Mojo::URL->new('https://some.hidden.pl/ews/exchange.asmx');

$url->userinfo(sprintf('%s\%s:%s', qw/bar foo baz/));

my $tx = $ua->get($url);

my $tx = $ua->build_tx(GET => $url);
$challenge = $ntlm->challenge;
$tx->req->headers->header('Authorization' => 'NTLM ' . $challenge);
$ua->start($tx);

$challenge = [ split /,\s*/, $tx->res->headers->header('www-authenticate') ]->[0] =~ s/NTLM //r;
$challenge = $ntlm->challenge($challenge);
my $tx = $ua->build_tx(GET => $url);
$tx->req->headers->header('Authorization' => 'NTLM ' . $challenge);
$ua->start($tx);

$tx = $ua->build_tx(POST => $url, {'Content-Type' => 'text/xml'}, $xml );
$tx->req->headers->content_type('text/xml');
$tx->req->headers->header('Authorization' => 'NTLM ' . $challenge);
$ua->start($tx);
print dump $tx->res;
```

but I keep getting a 401 at the second response from the server.

What am I getting wrong? And would it be easier to use Kerberos authentication (if so, how)?

thanks

Comment: Have you consired curl as an alternative?

Comment: I've tried curl in bash scripts - works like a charm. The perl libraries have a bit of a steep learning curve. I've also tried LWP::UserAgent with ntlm auth, which failed. Since this is part of a Mojolicious app I'd like to try and stick with  Mojo::UserAgent. I will try WWW::Mechanize and LWP::Protocol::Net::Curl too.

Comment: There is a [SPNEGO plugin](http://search.cpan.org/~agrolms/LWP-Authen-Negotiate-0.08/) für LWP, I reported a few bugs but the author refused to fixed them. I wouldn't use it.

Comment: do you have a working session with curl --debug? can you notice how its different from headers... mojo returns?

Comment: Yes and curl works fine. The first header that's sent is the same, but the subsequent ones differ - including the first challenge back from the server if I recall correctly (I'm not at work now)

Comment: ok thats great, when you get to it, copy the headers and challenge, and hardcode that into your Mojo code, and see what it generates -- it should generate the same response as curl ... i think, if it doesn't at least it gives you a direction for complaints (mojo or ntlm author) ; adding new protocol features requires too much research :)

Comment: I've done that - doesn't work either.

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't work"? can you add this new code to your post?

Answer (score 1):

I just published a new module that should be pretty helpful in this respect [`Mojolicious::Plugin::SPNEGO`](https://github.com/oetiker/mojolicious-plugin-spnego). It is pretty simple to use:

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;

my $SERVER = 'my-ad-server.example.com';

app->secrets(['My secret passphrase here']);

plugin 'SPNEGO', ad_server => $SERVER;

get '/' => sub {
   my $c = shift;
   if (not $c->session('user')){
       $c->ntlm_auth({
           auth_success_cb => sub {
               my $c = shift;
               my $user = shift;
               my $ldap = shift; # bound Net::LDAP::SPNEGO connection
               $c->session('user',$user->{samaccountname});
               $c->session('name',$user->{displayname});
               my $groups = $ldap->get_ad_groups($user->{samaccountname});
               $c->session('groups',[ sort keys %$groups]);
               return 1;
           }
       }) or return;
   }
} => 'index';

app->start;

__DATA__

@@ index.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>NTLM Auth Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello <%= session 'name' %></h1>
<div>Your account '<%= session 'user' %>' belongs to the following groups:</div>
<ul>
% for my $group (@{session 'groups' }) {
   <li>'<%= $group %>'</li>
% }
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

The module is based on the also newly released Net::LDAP::SPNEGO module which provides the basic buildingblocks for the SPNEGO dialog.

Comment: Thanks! How would this work with Exchange Web Services? Or do you have suggestion on how I would find the ad server for my organization?

Comment: What a beautiful solution and plugin @TobiOetiker Is there a way to *specify* a basedn, or I should just rely on the AD group?

Comment: you can either specify the baseDN in the object else it will ask the rootDSE for the 'defaultnamingcontext'

`Net::LDAP::SPNEGO->new($SERVER,baseDN=>....);`

note that all the things you can do with 'Net::LDAP' you can also do with Net::LDAP::SPNEGO.